# Use official microsoft dotnet docker image for dotnet builds on linux

Tags: .net, linux, visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I'm trying to build a dotnet project in a container off official microsoft/dotnet image on linux host since the image is compatible with both windows and linux. I only have linux host and so could only use this image to be used as container to be used for building dot net project. i am issuing command like below :-

```
dotnet build ****.sln **arguments**
```

The build fails with errors like below :-

```
The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.104/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/WebApplications/Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."
```

The dotnet project is based off dot net framework 4.7 and in my local i have visual studio etc so it works fine there, but how to make it work using microsoft/dotnet image based container on linux platform? Or is there any other image i can use for linux?

Comment: As far as i know,  .NET Core is supported in Linux, but .NET Framework is not. `microsoft/dotnet` is for .NET Core, and maybe your project is .NET Framework.

Comment: Yes so anyways we can do to make it work on linux? There has to be some image or some way to build a dot net project on linux platform?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.  .NET Framework is not compatible with Linux.  Your project would need to be based on .NET Core, which is compatible with Linux, in order for this to work.